# Letter formatting in Latex main and input files

Tags: input, letters

I have created a single file `('main.tex')`  for letter where I will add other tex files `('letter_1.tex')` using `\input` in Latex. The document format is letter (for cover letters). I am struggling with using the `\begin{letter}` and `\opening` commands in the `('letter_1.tex')` file as the compiler gives error. If I ignore these commands the compiler runs fine however the formatting is not that good. Please guide on how can I add these two commands and also flush the date to the right side as is normally written in letters.

The codes for the `main.tex` file is as following;

````
\documentclass[12pt]{letter} 

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% Entering the following five lines of the codes in ```main.tex``` and in ```letter_1.tex''' results in different margins output (I checked by entering in one file at a time before compiling)
\oddsidemargin=.2in
\evensidemargin=.2in
\textwidth=5.9in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in

\begin{document}

\input{letter_1}

\end{document}
````

The code for the letter_1.tex file is as following;

```
\today
% \begin{document}
% \begin{letter} {

Person ABC,\\
DEF Faculty,\\
GHI University,\\
Street 1, USA

% }

% \opening{
Dear ABC,
% }

My letter text goes here.

\closing{Yours Truly,

XYZ
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on the `letter` class, but a `\begin{***}` needs and `\end{***}`, so your `letter_1.tex` should read:

```
\begin{letter} {%
Person ABC,\\
DEF Faculty,\\
GHI University,\\
Street 1, USA%
}

\opening{Dear ABC,}

My letter text goes here.

\closing{Yours Truly,
    
XYZ}

\end{letter}
```

This produces:

[image]